# Anular5 - "this" not working within ready()

Tags: angular, typescript, callback

I have a graph.component.ts

```
this.cContainer = cytoscape ( {  
    ready: function(e) { 
      this._dataService.setResultData();
    }
  });
```

but I get
`ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'setResultData' of undefined`

..so `this` seems to be unknown, which looks correct because I am within a callback and so `this` is referred to the `ready`-callback.

but how would I call `_dataService.setResultData()` from inside this `ready()`-callback?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an arrow function to capture `this` from the declaring context. For `function` `this` is determined by the caller and will probably not be your class:

```
this.cContainer = cytoscape ( {  
    ready: (e) => { 
      this._dataService.setResultData();
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference regarding `this` between `function`s and fat-arrow ES6 functions. The latter version doesn't loose `this`. So instead of the current function you can use

`ready: e => this._dataService.setResultData();`

Edit: it could also be 

`ready: function(e) {
   this._dataService.setResultData();
}.bind(this)`

but it is just ugly...